# ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier returns email address not Id

Tags: .net-core, httpcontext

I'm using `HttpContext.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value` in my web API project to get the request user, for use with authentication. NameIdentifier returns the current user's email whereas a Google search suggests it should be returning the user's Id (Guid, in this case, if that matters).
Why is this happening, and how can i return the current user's id without a database query?

Comment: What authentication mechanism does the app use? What created the ClaimsPrincipal? Is it .NET Core 2.0?

Comment: Yes it's .NET Core 2.0. I'm using JwtBearer for authentication. I'm not familiar with ClaimsPrinciple, so i'd presume that JwtBearer is handling that?

Comment: Sorry, i meant Identity for authentication (using JwtBeaer for the jwt token)

Comment: did you find an answer to this question ? edit: found it a few seconds after, ima add an answer to this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I searched for a bit as I was having the same issue, and according to [this reply](https://community.auth0.com/t/how-to-get-the-user-identifier-in-an-asp-net-core-api/6735/2) on Auth0.com's forum, the JWT authentication handler in .NET will, for some reason, map the `sub` claim to the `NameIdentifier` claim type.

So the solution is not setting the `sub` claim type, or setting it to the id.

Comment: I can't confirm this works personally but I'll mark this as accepted answer because this is such an old an inactive question ;)

Answer (score 0):

I've faced same problem while using ASP.net core 2.0 since I generate jwt token like this

```
public ClaimsIdentity GenerateClaimsIdentity(string email, string id)
{
    return new ClaimsIdentity(new GenericIdentity(email, "Token"), new[]
    {
        new Claim(Helpers.Constants.Strings.JwtClaimIdentifiers.Id, id),
        new Claim(Helpers.Constants.Strings.JwtClaimIdentifiers.Rol, Helpers.Constants.Strings.JwtClaims.ApiAccess)
    });
}
```

I've tried to get `CurrentUser` by `UserManager` but it always returns `null`. I've figured to change `UserIdClaimType` string to "id" in startup file like this

```
var builder = services.AddIdentity<User,IdentityRole>(o =>
{
    // configure identity options
    o.Password.RequireDigit = false;
    o.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
    o.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
    o.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
    o.Password.RequiredLength = 6;

    //this line
    o.ClaimsIdentity.UserIdClaimType = "id";
});
```